# Read webpage and store in string without using libcurl. (C++)

Tags: c++, libcurl

What I want to do is read a webpage and then store it in a sting I know how to do this using libcurl but is there any other way to do this without using libcurl?(Using Cygwin to compile)

Comment: You can read the source for libcurl, and figure out how it does what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a simple HTTP request using raw sockets. But for other than learning exercises I would not recommend this and just go with libcurl.

For an example program which uses raw sockets look here: http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client (randomly found on google, quality not assured).

Answer (score 1):

While you can easily create an HTTP client using raw sockets as the other posters have suggested, I recommend against it if you want to deploy your software anywhere outside of your own computer. In the real world your users are likely to be behind proxies and firewalls, and may require authentication. Libraries like libCurl deal with this complexity for you.

If you really can't use libCurl and don't care about cross-platform code, most operating systems have built in APIs for accessing web pages. WinINET is the Windows library.

Comment: are you able to give me an example using WinINET. THX

Answer (score 0):

You can always speak HTTP directly yourself over a socket.